# Why is a variable in a different model not accessible?

Tags: javascript

I have been provided with the following code below:

```
var BaseViewModel = function(options) {

  var template = null;

  var initialise = function(options) {
    if (options) {
      if (options.template) {
        template = options.template;
      }
    }
  };

  var getTemplateId = function() {
    return template.Id;
  };

  return {
    initialise: initialise,
    template: template,
    getTemplateId: getTemplateId
  };

}


var MainViewModel = function () {

  this.prototype = new BaseViewModel();

  var base = this.prototype;

  var initialise = function() {
    base.initialise({ 
      template: {
        Id: 1,
        Name: '',
      }
    })

    console.log(base.template); // Q. Why is this null here?
    console.log(base.getTemplateId()); // This however will return a value!

  };

  return {
    initialise: initialise,
  };

}


var mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
mainViewModel.initialise();
```

[Link to JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/joqecibati/edit?js)

The `initialise()` method is called on the `MainViewModel`, which in turn calls `initialise()` on the `BaseViewModel()` with a template variable. The question I have is why can I not access the `base.template` at the given point in the `MainViewModel` after it has been initialised?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set

```
var template = null;
```

and return

```
return {
  init: init,
  template: template,
  getTemplateId: getTemplateId
};
```

After that updating `template`, it will not affect property value of constructed object because `template` is a primitive and hence is passed by value, it's not by reference.

In order to make it work the way you want you will need to update object property directly, for example like this:

```
var BaseViewModel = function(options) {

  var initialise = function(options) {
    if (options) {
      if (options.template) {
        instance.template = options.template;
      }
    }
  };

  var getTemplateId = function() {
    return instance.template.Id;
  };

  var instance = {
    template: null,
    initialise: initialise,
    getTemplateId: getTemplateId
  }

  return instance
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you use `var` you create a local or private variable.  When you use `this` you create a public or privileged variable (depending on how it is written).  Here is a more elaborate example showing the differences.

http://phrogz.net/js/classes/OOPinJS.html